# Vue 3 <setup script>- computed properties are not reactive?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-cli, vue-composition-api

I've just started using the composition API and `<script setup>` block and attribute.  So far I'm loving it (coming from vue 2) but I've had this weird issue I can't seem to get through.

I'm pulling a JSON object from my database that contains attributes (key:value pairs).  Since the key is dynamic (think `{ color:"blue", size:"medium" }`) I have to create a new object and add each attribute into it's own object specifying which is the key and which is the value.  So `{ color:"blue"}` becomes: `{ key: "color", value: "blue }` which allows me to bind it to inputs in my `<template>`.  When the page loads, it parses the attributes into the new object, and displays them in inputs.

[image]

If a user wants to add an attribute, they can click a button to create a new "row" for attributes.  Problem is when they click the plus button, the attributes object is updated, but it doesn't reflect on the form (not reactive).   I'm honestly not sure why.  Here is my `<script>`:

```js
<script setup>

import { computed, reactive } from "vue";
import { getProductByID } from "@/composables/products";

const props = defineProps({
  productid: String,
});

const { product, error, loadProduct} = getProductByID(props.productid);
loadProduct();

const attributes = reactive({
    english: computed(() => {
      if (product.value.attributes && Object.keys(product.value.attributes).length > 0) {
      
        let newValues = [];

        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(product.value.attributes)) {
          let s = {};
          s["key"] = key;
          s["value"] = value;
          newValues.push(s);
        }
        return newValues;
      }
      return {};
    })
  });
```

NOTE: the product returned from the composable is wrapped in `ref{}`:

```js
import axios from "axios";
import { ref } from "vue";

const product = ref({});
const error = ref(null);
...
return {product, error, loadProduct}
```

The attributes are bound to the input properly:

```html
<div id="attributes">
  <!-- English Attributes -->
  <div>
    <div>
      <label>Attributes (property : value) </label>
      <button @click.prevent="addAttributeInput">
        <span class="icon">
          <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
        </span>
      </button>
    </div> 
    <div v-for="(attribute, index) in attributes.english" :key="index">
      <div>
        <input v-model="attributes.english[index]['key']" placeholder="attribute" />
      </div>
      <div class="control">
        <span>:</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input v-model="attributes.english[index]['value']" placeholder="value" />
      </div>
      <button @click.prevent="removeAttributeInput(key)">
        <span class="icon">
          <i class="fas fa-minus"></i>
        </span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If the user wants to add (or remove) an attribute, there's a button that adds a blank object to the `attributes.english` object:

```js
function addAttributeInput() {
  attributes.english.unshift({"key":"", "value":""});
}

function removeAttributeInput(index) {
  attributes.english.splice(index, 1);
}
```

When I click these buttons, it **does** modify the attributes.english object (I see it in the vue tools in browser) but it doesn't update the form reactively.  Does wrapping the `attributes` object with `reactive()` not make it reactive?

Comment: Don't change the type of reactive object, it's not documented how it will behave, like that `return {};`. There's no need to pack `english` inside `attributes`. And likely the actual problem is that you mutate a computed with v-model, that's a mistake. If you expect `english` to react to `product` changes, do this in a watcher, not computed

Comment: I use `english` because the database returns attributes in spanish too (separate db field).  Would it be better to separate the english and spanish into two objects and wrap in `reactive()` ?  And I'm returning a blank object `return {}` if there are no attributes being returned from the database.

Comment: If `english` is supposed to be an array you shouldn't make it an object accidentally, that's the problem with `return {}`. If there are multiple languages it's possible that they need to be handled in a more general way in the app. But it's likely it should be `const attributes = reactive({ english: [], spanish: [] })` for now, modify it in a watcher

Comment: It comes in from the db as an object.

Comment: It's not about received data but data that's in the state. It's used as an array, like `english.unshift()`. You need to keep `english` either an array or object, not both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you can't mutate `computed()` props by the usage of a `v-model` (if it isn't writable). Therefor, this can't work.

Of course, there are multiple options to solve your problem. I made a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-mgey2h?file=src/App.vue) to show how to do it with the usage of a `watch()` which sets the value of a `ref()`.

It depends on the use-case but it could be better to make use of a [writable computed](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html#writable-computed).

Comment: It's quite documented iirc. A computed is read-only ref that is unwrapped when used in reactive object like `reactive`, so it becomes read-only property. You can mutate computed object but this may affect the reactivity in unpredictable way, and the changes will be silently overwritten when a computed is retriggered,

Comment: @EstusFlask Do you have any examples of documentation? Maybe I should have clarified a bit more but you would use `reactive()` for properties that you want to be mutable, as that is it's purpose overall. Therefor it doesn't make much sense to have a immutable property inside it. That's why it's fine to use `ref()` in combination with `reactive()`. This is just how I understood it from the documentation and previous experiences. But if you can proof me otherwise, please do!

Comment: `reactive` deeply transforms (proxies) an object to reactive object, including all its properties, writable or not. It's controllable here at the top level but could happen at any level and still would need to be handled somehow. Ref unwrapping is explicitly documented https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#ref-unwrapping-in-reactive-objects . I'm not sure if the docs say how readonly/computed refs are unwrapped but this is documented with TS types.

Comment: If you want an example of a legit use of this, let's say we need to pass reactive context obj somewhere, like with provide/inject, but at the same time one of the props is read-only, i.e. something that's usually represented with a computed. What the OP showed is exactly the way how this could be done, like `provide('foo', reactive({ bar: ..., baz: computed(...) })`, so `inject('foo').bar` is writable, and `inject('foo').baz` isn't, otherwise there would be a need to group writable and non-writable props to different objects

Comment: Hm, okay. I get your point. I edited my answer to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thank you!!  I don't know why I didn't consider the problem being trying to mutate a computed property.  That makes so much sense.  I moved the `attributes[]` array into my composable as a ref and am bringing it in when I get the product from the db, allowing me to mutate it from the component.  Many thanks!